# Convert MSComm VB6 to C#

Tags: c#, vb6

I am trying to send some data to a LCD display that works over serial port. This code does the job over VB6 but i needed to convert it to C#. Sadly it does not work. Any ideas?

VB6 (Example)

```
MSComm1.CommPort = 1
MSComm1.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
MSComm1.PortOpen = True
MSComm1.Output = Chr(2)
MSComm1.Output = Trim(Text1.Text)
```

C# (Example)

```
var serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
serialPort1.Open();
serialPort1.Write(((char)2).ToString());
serialPort1.Write(textbox1.Text);
serialPort1.Close();
```

I think the problem is about serialPort1.Write function but i could not figure it out. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try this helper extension method to make writing one-byte control codes easier

```
public static void Write(this SerialPort sp, byte b)
{
   sp.Write(new byte[]{b}, 0, 1);
}
```

Then change your code to this:

```
var serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
serialPort1.Encodeing = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
serialPort1.Open();
serialPort1.Write(2);
serialPort1.Write(textbox1.Text.Trim());
serialPort1.Close();
```

Please note that I didn't syntax check this but just free-handed it so you might need to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> Sadly it does not work

Given this broad statement, I will assume it's a difference between data types since `Chr` returns a value between 0 and 255, i.e., a byte.

```
serialPort1.Write(new byte[]{2}, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

i make a byte array

```
byte[] bytSend;
```

i fill the byte array with the data to be sent
then i send the data with the following command

```
sp.Write(bytSend, 0,bytSend.GetUpperBound(0) + 1);
```

from the top of my head, so no real test project for you, sorry